# JS: Can't click one element to trigger click on another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I followed the examples that I found but for some reason clicking on the above div won't trigger a click on the below input. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").click(); 
});
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
    
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you want actually  through text input box click. as clicking on text-inputbox will do nothing?

Comment: Are you're trying to upload file?  If yes, using `<input type="file">` instead

Comment: but it works fine :/

Comment: If you need to start typing after the click, you can try `.focus()` instead

Comment: Click is actually happening, but there is no click handler in first place to catch that event. Just add `$('#url').click(function(event) {
  console.log( 'Input element was clicked' )
});` and then check console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the click to focus on the `#url` element, use [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) instead of [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").focus(); 
});
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
    
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope on click of div ***you want to show file upload window.***

For that Convert `type="text"` to `type="file"` and it will work fine.

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) {
  $("#url").click(); 
});
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
  <input type="file" name="url" id="url">
</body>
</html>
```

***Note:-***

Your code is working fine, but there is no click handler written to catch that event. So notting happening

You can assure by adding click handler to your code like below:-

```js
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) {
  $("#url").focus();  // you can apply .click() too
});

/* for click add the even handler like below 
$('#url').click(function(){
  $(this).val('Hey click worked!').focus();
});

*/
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, I don't want a file input, I want a text input for a URL.

Comment: @RobKwasowski  i have added that too in my answer

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").click(); 
});
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 250px;
  line-height: 250px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
    
    <input type="file" name="url" id="url" onclick="console.log('clicked!!')">

</body>
</html>
```

I guess you want to open native file browser window on click. Check the snippet, there in an click handler attached to the input too.
You can use this for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").click(); 
});
```

Use like this

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").trigger('click); 
});
```

Comment: As far as I know, they are the same.

Comment: They act differently, I had same issue solved by this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing an click event for the *#url* element?

When triggering a click event for an element using *.click()* you have to define an actual click event for it.

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploader', function(event) { 
    $("#url").click(); 
});

$("#url").click(function(){ 
    alert('asd');
});
```

This could be the only reason, unless the scripts aren't loaded properly, or you are getting some errors while running your JS.

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1frdhma/)

In case you want the click event to focus on your input element, you'd use *.focus()*, as described in a previous answer written by Alive to Die.

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44ptdre6/)

Answer (score 1):

> **Click & Focus, just modify few code**

```js
$('#uploader').on('click', function(event) { 
    $("#url").click().focus(); 
});
```

```css
#uploader {
  width: 480px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 150px;
  border: 2px dashed #443d66;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #777;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>

  <div id="uploader">
    Click
  </div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" onclick="alert('clicked!!')">

</body>
</html>
```